# Do mutations in one bacterial strain have the same effect in other strains within the same species?

Tags: bioinformatics, proteins, bacteriology, mutations

I would assume so, since they are the same species after all. I am asking this because I am doing a bioinformatics project for school and I cannot find any protein mutations for the specific bacterial strains that my department has managed to isolate. The proteins I have identified as stress proteins are within their genomes, but there is no known mutations I have found while perusing the literature. Mutations for these proteins are present in other strains though. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Different strains of the same species have differents genotypes (ie different alleles and therefore express different proteins).So if your protein A in strain 1 has some effect, it could have the same effect in strain 2, but not necessarily.
Indeed lets imagine that protein A interact with protein B in strain 1 to produce an effect. If protein B is absent in strain 2, or different, protein A will have no effect. My point is if you have a mutation in one strain, the same mutation would not necessarily have the same effect (although it is very likely) in an another strain beacause both strain don't express the same proteome.

Comment: Hi welcome to Bio.SE! We ask that answers be well supported and/or cited in order to improve the quality of our answers in this community. Please provide support/references for your answer.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, I did not know that. I'm afraid I have no english reference to cite. It is just basic population genetics : in a population the individuals are not clones but show genetic diversity.

Comment: If you provide sources, it will probably be reasonably simply to find English translations, so don't worry about that :)